# if record is null, how to make the code continue to run in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net

I met a problem in ASP.NET core code, may you help me?

In the following code, if Device.photo is null, how to make the code continue to run?

```cs
 public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            Device Device = GetDevice(id);

            ViewBag.Base64String = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Device.photo, 0, Device.photo.Length);

            return View(Device);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do not tag ASP.NET for ASP.NET Core questions! To be fair though the question isn't really specific to ASP.NET, Core or otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling null at all, so if `Device.photo` is null, it will throw an exception because it can't do a `ToBase64String` on null + `.Length` isn't possibly a property either. Next time it would have been great with a full description on how your Device and photo class looks like, or atleast tell us the datatype.

```
public IActionResult Details(int id) 
{ 
   Device Device = GetDevice(id);
   if (Device.photo != null) {
      ViewBag.Base64String = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(Device.photo, 0, Device.photo.Length);
   }

   return View(Device);
}
```